# How to get function arguments by decoration in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I want to use decoration to implement this but something is wrong. I don't know how can I get data from a function in decoration.

```
class CalcClass{

  @subtract(1)
  @multiply(2)
  addOne(number:number) {
      return number+1;
  }
}

console.log(new CalcClass().addOne(2))

function subtract(number:number) {
  return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    descriptor.value = number - 1;
    return descriptor.value;
  };
}

function multiply(number:number) {
  return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    descriptor.value = number * 2;
        return descriptor.value;
  };
}
```

Comment: Can [this](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/the-anatomy-of-decorators-in-angular-d7972bf9e865#4bc2) be of help?

Comment: Did you see this link? [How to use decoration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74263055/how-to-use-decoration-in-typescript?noredirect=1#comment131110956_74263055)

Comment: [*something is wrong* is not an adequate description of your problem](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: @Farinaz Yes I did but it doesn't help me. My question is so complicated.

Comment: Please [read the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html) and let us know if you have a question that can be answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will just assume you want to modify the return value of your function with the decorators. Then we can implement them like this:

```js
class CalcClass{

  @subtract(1)
  @multiply(2)
  addOne(number:number) {
      return number+1;
  }
}

console.log(new CalcClass().addOne(2))

function subtract(number:number) {
  return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    const originalFunction = descriptor.value; // save the original function

    // overwrite the function with another function that calls the original, but does some extra work
    descriptor.value = (...args: any[]) => originalFunction(...args) - number;
  };
}

function multiply(number:number) {
  return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    const originalFunction = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = (...args: any[]) => originalFunction(...args) * number;
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Garuno my problem has been fixed.